# Obtaining exact decimals in bisection method

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, estimation

While studying the bisection for the approximation of roots of non-linear equations I was given the following bound for the error:

$|x_n-s| \leq \frac{(b-a)}{2^{n+1}}$

where $x_n$ is the n-th approximation of the root. Now consider the following problem:

> Proof that the equation $x^3+4x^2=10$ has a unique solution on [1,2].
>   Using the bisection method give an approximation of the solution with
>   at least 5 exact decimals.

The problem is I don't know what error should I use, in my class they worked out n from the following expression $\frac{1}{10^5}>\frac{2-1}{2^{n+1}}$.

Now what confuses me comes from the **following hypothetical situation**

Say the exact result is $1.00001$ and the error is $0.000005$ then between the posible approximations is $1.000005$ (substracting the error) and then I wouldn't have 5 exact decimals.

I need someone to point me out what am I missing here. Is it an error theory concept I'm missing? Should take another bound for the error?

Comment: The exact result is between 1 and 2, so it's certainly not 0.00001. More generally, the exact result has a 1 in the one's place, so the digits immediately trailing it will be significant.

Comment: I just edited to fit the example with the problem proposed

Comment: If the exact result is 1.00001 and you perform 17 bisections (as the formula dictates), then you'll obtain an approximation of $1+2^{-17}=1.000008$ or $1.00001$ rounded up. So, you've got your 5 digits.

Comment: @Mark McClure I have just edited my post to insist that the situation proposed (not the actual exercise) is hypothetical, that is the kind of situation I need to solve. Also, note that I'm interested to know a priori what should be the bound to the error to obtain 5 exact decimal and not on how many bisections I could do.

Comment: It seems to me the formula $\frac{1}{10^5}>\frac{2-1}{2^{n+1}}$ implies you can use just $16$ bisections, which (I think) is not enough. There seems to be a factor of two missing. The other problem is, suppose that the _actual_ exact (real-valued) answer is $1.0000148$, so that the result correct to five decimal places is $1.00001$, but you do bisections until you arrive at the value $1+2^{-16} \approx 1.0000153$ and your formula tells you you're "accurate enough", at which point you round _up_ to $1.00002$. That's what bugs _me_ about this method.

Comment: @DavidK We have $\frac{1}{10^5} = \frac{2-1}{2^{n+1}}$ when $n\approx16.6$, so I would say you need 17 bisections, which is just right. And Rodrigo, we *are* talking about your hypothetical scenario. I'm not sure I see the confusion.

Comment: @MarkMcClure $(2-1)/2^{16+1} = 2^{-17} \approx 7.63×10^{-6} < 10^{-5}$, which is why I thought the formula in the question said $16$ bisections, and why I thought there was a factor of two missing in that formula.

Comment: @DavidK Ah yes - you're right. I neglected the $+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the
"table makers dilemma",
where a result is
so close to $\frac12$
after the last decimal place wanted
that there is no way
to decide what the last digit shown
should be.

Look it up - 
Google returns a number
of quite relevant links.

Answer (score 2):

Formally, your concern about crossing a breakpoint is well founded.  We could have a problem where the true answer is $1.0000050000000000000001$  As you approach it with bisection your intervals will cross $1.000005$ until they get *very* small.  To be sure you have the correct rounded five decimal expression, you need a lot of steps.  To get the minimum number of steps, you would need to check after each step that the uncertainty range remaining crosses $1.000005$.

Less formally, we are not so concerned about breakage and rounding.  We would say we want an answer that is correct within some range, say $\pm 0.000005$  This, or even with a few more zeros, is not enough to guarantee that it will round correctly, but you can quote the result as $1.0000050 \pm 0.000005$.  You have given a range that includes the correct result.  Anyone who sees your result should be able to tell if it is precise enough for his purpose.  Now you can compute exactly how many steps of bisection are required because you know the range gets cut in half each step.